# Parsing text to return date

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to have a textbox where I can add an age as {a} y {b} m {c} w where y=years, m=months, w=weeks and a submit button and I want this to return a parsed birth date according to the age expression.

For example I want 2y 1 m / 2 yr 1 mon to return 2013/09/27. (the difference from today and the parsed date)

How can I do this in ASP.MVC? Every approach is ok...using C#, javascript...

Thank you!

Comment: you have to be more specific.. do you want to do this using javascript, c#, VB, jquery, ajax, post

Comment: using postback... In javascript or C# it would be better

Comment: This is too vague.  What have you tried already?

Comment: I have a textbox and I tried to parse the text, but I don't get any good solution to this. Also, I don't know how to make the difference between the values to get the correct date.

Comment: The problem I see is that you have no control over what a user will enter, so trying to cater for multiple variations will be difficult. Can you use a datepicker? or selectlists - one for day, one for month, one for year?

Comment: DateTime objects have AddYears, AddMonths and AddDays.. just figure out how you want to get the Y M and W and use those to get the date.. `var date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(intYears * -1).AddMonths(intMonths * -1).AddDays(intWeeks * -7).Date;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would first create a View Model

**View Model**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int Years { get; set; }
    public int Months { get; set; }
    public int Weeks { get; set; }
}
```

Then on your view you would pass that in by using `@model ViewModel` at the top.

Then once you have submitted some sort of form you can do something like the following:

```
public DateTime Calcuate()
{
    var result = DateTime.UtcNow;

    result = result.AddYears(ViewModel.Years*-1).AddMonths(ViewModel.Months*-1).AddDays(ViewModel.Weeks*-7);
    return result;
}
```